# Vim Gemfile recognition

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

When I open a `Gemfile` in vim, I don't automatically get the colors for the code. I have to do manually `:set syntax=ruby`.

Is there a simple way to automate this ?

Comment: Can you create a ~/.vim/filetype.vim which sets the filetype to ruby for GEM files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are running Vim 7.3, or if you have installed a recent version of the [`vim-ruby` plugin](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby) (any version newer than December 2009), then this should already be happening—they both arrange to set `filetype=ruby` for files named `Gemfile`.

If do not want to install `vim-ruby`, then you can still automatically use your existing Ruby support on files named `Gemfile` by putting this in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead Gemfile set filetype=ruby
```

You can skip this line if you decide to install `vim-ruby` to get the benefits of its updated indenting/highlighting/completion (`vim-ruby` automatically does the above `autocmd`).